# Google Maps Taking Screenshots with Puppeteer not show

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have page for showing main image, google maps and description
when access from browser it's running but delay show maps a few milliseconds.

Problem on puppeteer where scr are faster than displaying maps.

this my code:

```
const uniq_1st = generateUniqueChars(item.trx_id);
const photo_name_1st = `${item.trx_id}.png`;
const url_1st = `${_web_url_and_params}`;

  const page1 = await browser.newPage();
  await page1.setViewport({ width: 390, height: 520 });

  try {

    await page1.goto(url_1st, {waitUntil : "networkidle0"});
    //waitUntil networkidle0, networkidle5, load, domdocumentload
    //await page1.waitForSelector(".map");
    await page1.screenshot({ path: `${dir_dest}/${photo_name_1st}`, type: 'png' });

    console.log("Success Capturing 1st photo: ", photo_name_1st);
    // console.log("Success capturing 1st photo");
    // console.log("------------------------------");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", error.message);
    console.log("OMG! Failed to capture: ", url_1st);
  } finally {
    await page1.close();
  }
```

and this for view:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Map Photo Other Information</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="<?php echo $data['foto_raw']; ?>" />
      </div>


      <div id="map" class="map" class="map-wrapper" style="width:120px; height: 100px; position: relative; left: 0px;top: 30px;"></div>
      <div class="desc-wrapper">
        <p class="address">
          <?php
          echo "<br />". $data['address']; 
          ?>
        </p>

        <p class="address">
          <?php
          echo $data['latitute'] . ',' . $data['longitute']; 
          ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initMap() 
      {
        var myLatLng = { lat: <?php echo $data['latitute']; ?>, lng: <?php echo $data['longitute']; ?>  };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          zoom: 15
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Location'
        });
      }
      initMap();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

has been using **await page1.waitForSelector(".map");** or **await page1.waitFor(2000);** before screenshot but not working.

Comment: Are you trying to screenshot a google maps instance?